# styling product descriptions using jCoverflip

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am having trouble styling the text under the images. I have tried inline styles but nothing seems to be working out. I need for the name of the product to be a larger font size than the rest of the text. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

- Mike

http://mikedemar.com/stromasys/jcoverflip/index01.html

Comment: What kind of control do you have over the text? Is it possible to introduce tags? Then you might be able to set the text to:

'<span class="large">CHARON-AXP/DS20</span> <br />
Up to two (2) virtual [..]' and style .large accordingly

Comment: @DZittersteyn Thanks for your input. Whenever I introduce span tags to the text it renders out of place. See attached link... 
http://mikedemar.com/stromasys/jcoverflip/index02.html

Comment: Crickey, the html for that part now is:       <li title="<span class="large">CHARON-AXP/DS10 [..] /></li>. That shouldn't be happening ;).  It might be that you're entering the data in the wrong spot, but more likely it's a quirk of jCoverflip, with which I'm not experienced. 'fraid I can't help you much further with this, hope some other SO'ers will help you soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/QmVFR/

Add

```
#flip>li>.content{display:none;}

#flip>li.selected>.content{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    font-size:11px;
    z-index:1;
    text-align:center;
    width:500px;
    padding-left:50%;
    margin-left:-250px;
}

#flip>li.selected>.content>.title{font-size:16px;display:block!important;}

#scrollbar{top:320px;}
```

Change your HTML to

```
<ul id="flip">

<li>
    <img src="http://mikedemar.com/stromasys/jcoverflip/images/1.png" />
    <div class="content">
        <p class="title">CHARON-AXP/DS10</p>
        <p>Up to two (2) virtual CPUs</p>
        <p>Up to 32GB of Alpha memory.</p>
        <p>Run OpenVMS or Tru64 with no changes</p>
        <p>Supports Windows, Linux and VMware</p>
        <p>Pricing starts at $9,500.00 USD</p>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="http://mikedemar.com/stromasys/jcoverflip/images/2.png" />
    <div class="content">
        <p class="title">CHARON-AXP/GS80</p>
        <p>Up to eight (8) virtual CPUs</p>
        <p>Up to 32GB of Memory</p>
        <p>Run OpenVMS or Tru64 with no changes</p>
        <p>Supports Windows, Linux and VMware</p>
        <p>Pricing starts at $49,000</p>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="http://mikedemar.com/stromasys/jcoverflip/images/5.png" />
    <div class="content">
        <p class="title">CHARON-AXP/DS20</p>
        <p>Up to two (2) virtual CPUs</p>
        <p>Up to 32GB of Alpha memory.</p>
        <p>Run OpenVMS or Tru64 with no changes</p>
        <p>Supports Windows, Linux and VMware</p>
        <p>Pricing starts at $12,200</p>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="http://mikedemar.com/stromasys/jcoverflip/images/4.png" />
    <div class="content">
        <p class="title">A title for the image</p>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="http://mikedemar.com/stromasys/jcoverflip/images/6.png" />
    <div class="content">
        <p class="title">CHARON-VAX/6620</p>
        <p>Up to six (6) virtual CPUs</p>
        <p>Up to 3 GB of Memory</p>
        <p>Run OpenVMS with no changes</p>
        <p>Supports Windows and VMware</p>
        <p>Pricing starts at 65,000</p>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="http://mikedemar.com/stromasys/jcoverflip/images/7.png" />
    <div class="content">
        <p class="title">A title for the image</p>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

And add

```
jQuery('#flip>li.selected').removeClass('selected');
el.addClass('selected');
```

at the beginning of `currentCss` function.

Comment: Thanks so much @Oriol This worked perfectly! 

http://mikedemar.com/stromasys/jcoverflip/

Comment: Thanks again for helping me out with styling the product descriptions for this project. I am now facing a new challenge of having the images cycle and loop. Any ideas on how to add this functionality?

Comment: Any idea how to stop the images from rotating once you click or hover over an image?

Comment: @Mike You could add an event listener and clear the interval using `clearInterval(timer)`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

The test that you want to make bigger in size, just add a span tag with it, because u cant make it separate as the whole text is using "#flip .ui-jcoverflip--title" css.

Use additional span tag for bigger text eg:
    <span style="font-size:15px"> CHARON-AXP/DS20     </span>

you can use an additional class with "#flip .ui-jcoverflip--title .myfont" , and give that span the myfont class name.
Hope this will help.

Comment: How should I write in the span class? like this? 

<li title="<span class="font-size:15px">CHARON-AXP/DS10 </span><br /> Up to two (2) virtual CPUs <br /> Up to 32GB of Alpha memory. <br /> Run OpenVMS or Tru64 with no changes <br /> Supports Windows, Linux and VMware </br>Pricing starts at $9,500.00 USD" ><img src="images/1.png" /></li>

Comment: nope, don't add class for now.. make it style= with single quote.. so in place of class="font-size:15px" use like  style='font-size:15px'

Comment: Use this : <li title="<span style='font-size:15px'>CHARON-AXP/DS10 </span><br /> Up to two (2) virtual CPUs <br /> Up to 32GB of Alpha memory. <br /> Run OpenVMS or Tru64 with no changes <br /> Supports Windows, Linux and VMware </br>Pricing starts at $9,500.00 USD" ><img src="images/1.png" /></li>